# RegEx matching a something between two numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match results that contain either 4 numbers or 6 numbers, nothing else.
I have tried using `(?!5)` or `(?!\d)` at the end but it still matches input of 5 numbers, I feel like I have tried everything.

**It returns the second test as a match.**

Tests:

```
 [Test]
  [TestCase("1234", Result=true)]
  [TestCase("12345", Result=false)]
  [TestCase("a234", Result=false)]
  [TestCase("", Result=false)]
```

Code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Program 
{
    public static bool ValidatePIN(string pin) 
    {
        string pattern = @"[1-9]{4}|[1-9]{6}(?!5)";
        Regex rg = new Regex(pattern); 
        Match match = rg.Match(pin);
        
        if (match.Success) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for *anchor*? `@"^([1-9]{4}|[1-9]{6})$";`, please, note `^` and `$` which are beginning and end of the string

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean by that, but using ^ in the beginning does not give back a any different results.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo, I've skipped parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you should use *achors*

```
 ^([1-9]{4}|[1-9]{6})$
```

here

```
 ^                   - beginning of the string
 ([1-9]{4}|[1-9]{6}) - either 4 or 6 digits 
 $                   - end of the string
```

You can wrap it into the method as

```
public static bool ValidatePIN(string pin) =>
  Regex.IsMatch(pin, @"^([1-9]{4}|[1-9]{6})$");
```

Another possibility is Linq:

```
public static bool ValidatePIN(string pin) =>
  pin != null &&
 (pin.Length == 4 || pin.Length == 6) &&
  pin.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did indeed work. However, I don't really understand how this works. Does the $ not include anything that comes after?

Comment: @Confused Newbie: `\z` is more accurate then `$`, since `$` can mean "end of line", for details, please see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference;

Comment: This could also be described as exactly 4 digits with optionally (exactly) two more: `^(\d{4}(?:\d{2})?)$` - which yields 4 & 6 digit numbers, but not <4,5,>6

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static bool IsValid(string s)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, "^([\\d]{4}|[\\d]{6})$");
    }
```